# In supervised learning, what does "Estimating $p(y \vert x)$" mean?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning, probability

I read chapter 5.1.3 of Joshua Bengio's [deeplearning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html), which says:
supervised learning involve observing examples of random vectors $\textbf{x}$ and associated value or vector $\textbf{y}$ and learning to predict $\textbf{y}$ from $\textbf{x}$ by estimating $p(\textbf{y} \vert \textbf{x})$.

What does $p(\textbf{y} \vert \textbf{x})$ mean?

From basic statistics, I know that $p(\textbf{y} \vert \textbf{x})=\frac{p(\textbf{y},\textbf{x})}{p(\textbf{x})}$.
How do we find $p(\textbf{y},\textbf{x})$ and  $p(\textbf{x})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that 
\begin{equation*}
p(y|\mathbf{x})=\dfrac{p(\mathbf{x},y)}{p(\mathbf{x})}.
\end{equation*}
Similarly, we can write the joint probability $p(\mathbf{x},y)$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
p(\mathbf{x},y)=p(\mathbf{x}|y)\cdot p(y)
\end{equation*}
From the above two equations, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
p(y|\mathbf{x})=\dfrac{p(\mathbf{x}|y)\cdot p(y)}{p(\mathbf{x})}
\end{equation*}
In the context of supervised learning, the variable $y$ is used to denote the class labels, and  the vector $\mathbf{x}$ for measurement vector or feature vector. For the purpose of discussion, let us assume that the class label $y$ takes values in the set $\{1,2\}$, where $1$ denotes  `male` and $2$ denotes `female`. Similarly, $\mathbf{x}$ is a measurement vector on two variables say, $(x_{1},x_{2})$, where $x_{1}$ stands for `height` and $x_{2}$ stands for `weight` of individuals.

$p(y|\mathbf{x})$ denote the posterior density for $y$ given the observation $\mathbf{x}$. For example, $p(1|\mathbf{x})$ means that given the observation  $\mathbf{x}$, what is the probability that sample belongs to the class `males`. Similarly, we can interpret $p(2|\mathbf{x})$.
$p(\mathbf{x}|y)$ stands for the class conditional probability density. For example, $p(\mathbf{x}|1)$ denote the probability density for males and $p(\mathbf{x}|2)$ denote the probability  density for females respectively. In supervised learning, these class conditional densities are usually known in advance. Finally $p(y)$ denote the prior probability for the class label $y$. For example, $p(1)$ denotes the probability that an individual/example selected randomly from the population is a `male`.

Assuming that, the prior probabilities for the classes and class conditional densities are known, Bayes rule says, assign an observation $x_{0}$ whose class label is not known, to the class, say, `male`, if
\begin{equation*}
p(\mathbf{x_{0}}|1)p(1)>p(\mathbf{x_{0}}|2)p(2).
\end{equation*}
Note that, $p(\mathbf{x})$ is not used in the classifier. Classification rules usually require class conditional densities.

Answer (score 1):

$P(y|x)$ stands for the *probability of y occurring, given x has occurred*.

Using bayes theorem, this can also be written as:

$P(y|x) = \frac {{P(x|y) \times P(y)}}{ P(x)}$

It is these values that you generally know and can use.

Comment: Why has this been down voted?

Comment: I have vote it up

Answer (score 0):

Say $x$ is *sex* and $y$ is *employed*. You can restate your $p(y|x)$ as:

$$ p(employed=1~|~sex=male) $$

Now, it's a simple matter of counting the relevant examples or looking up in the appropriate [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).